# PHP $_FILES file loop upload

Tags: php, loops, file, upload

I want to insert files into mysql from php function.
The files that need to be uploaded are already present on the server, so I don't want to use the upload form.

I want to loop through the directory and get the files info into `$_FILES`.

Please let me know how I will get the `$file` into `$_FILES` and then call upload.

```
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open folder");

while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) {
  echo "$file";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_FILES is solely for handling files uploaded to the script by the client. You should be able to insert the file contents using `file_get_contents()` or `fopen()/fread()` without further ado.

Comment: Hi Pekka, 
I have to actually load that file as blob in mysql. There is a function which is already doing it. I have to just call it.

$fileName = $_POST["name"]; 
$filePath = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']; 
echo File::upload($fileName, $filePath);

I want to use the $filePath..

Comment: $file in your loop should be identical to $filePath from your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are already on the server then they don't need to be "uploaded". They just need to be moved.

You could try something like...

```
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open folder");

while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) {
    // example query may be...
    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO table SET filename = %s", mysql_escape_string($path . "/" . $file));
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, 
I want to upload the files into mysql DB(blobs). The fuction already exists. Now I want to populate the $filePath with the file data and call the upload fuction..

$fileName = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$filePath = filter_var($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

echo File::upload($pid, $fileName, $filePath);

Comment: If you are wanting to get the contents of the file then you could do what Pekka mentioned and just use file_get_contents or the fopen/fread combo then add it to your insert