# PHP Module modifying $_POST, $_FILES

Tags: php, zend-framework, cakephp, zend-form

I would like to write a PHP Module that will modify the $_POST and $_FILES variables. The goal is to do preprocessing in the module, for instance, normalizing input, not allowing fies with certain extensions.

Is this possible? It seems that [you can't modify the $_FILES variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796628/php-files-file-loop-upload) but, if you have an extension, you might be able to [modify these variables during the RINIT phase](http://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend/).

How can I do this?

EDIT: Clarification

I guess normalizing data wasn't a great example. I'm more interested in how it could be done and learning more about PHP and modules.

As an example, there is a [function that reorganizes $_files](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php#109958). I thought it would be fun to write a module that would automatically do that, just as an academic exercise and was looking for pointers on where to start.

Comment: "normalizing input" - as some universal solution is a bad idea. Data normalization, validation and sanitizing is a very domain-specific process. So it's not possible to write something generic (and safe) enough.

Comment: "I thought it would be fun to write a module that would automatically do that" -- actually modifying the superglobals is never a fun. They are of a specific format, so it would be confusing if you change it.

Comment: "and was looking for pointers on where to start" --- you've already found ready to use function. Isn't that a "pointer"? Just take it and use

Comment: Yeah. Just wanted to know how to make a module and packaging etc. Part of the point was to figure out how, if at all, you could modify a superglobal.

Comment: (in particular, modifying $_FILES from a php module).

Comment: what do you mean by "php module"?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would be better to encapsulate the "request" as an object with (POST/GET and even FILES etc). Then only refer to this object instead of the individual variable scopes.

This will allow you to create a new instance of said object and execute any methods of your choosing, or work with it in client code throughout your "module" (you could modify/normalise it as well). In addition, there is no need to modify the supermodels while doing so.

Very quick illustration which could easily be expanded upon:

```
  class Request
  {
    protected $params = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
      return $this;
    }

    public function getParam($key)
    {
      if (isSet($_params[$key])) {
        return $_POST[$key];
      } else if (isSet($_GET[$key])) {
        return $_GET[$key];
      } else if ($_POST[$key]) {
        return $_POST[$key];
      } else if ($_FILES[$key]) {
        // do something special with files here
      }
    }

    public function setParam($key, value);

    public function getParams();

    public function getPostParams();

    ...etc...etc
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

'Normalizing' your data is likely going to be very context specific, so I wouldn't recommend what you are suggesting.

If you really wanted to, though, I'd recommend writing a function that takes the assoc array ($_FILES, $_POST) and modifies them as you please, and returns a new assoc array with the data you want. Don't forget to move the file from its location (`$_FILES['file1']['tmp_name']`).

But yeah, writing a whole module seems redundant. Don't so it. :P

Comment: (Moved edit to the actual post as it seemed more suited there)